# break_test module from stastmodels in Python

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I want to use the below packge however it seems like i need to install the correct package but not sure which one. Any guidance is highly apprecited.statsmodels and arch are already installed in my machine.

from statsmodels.tsa.regime_switching import break_test